# How to directly fade to another image (without any delay) using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fade, onhover

My code works but it doesn't fade to second image directly: fades out first image -> delay -> fades in second one. How do I fade directly to second image?

My jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var std = $(".fadeim").attr("src");
    var hover = std.replace(".png", "-hover.png");
    $(".fadeim")
        .mouseover(function() {   
            $(this).fadeOut("fast",function(){  
                $(this).attr("src", hover);  
                $(this).fadeIn("fast");  
            });  
        })  
        .mouseout(function() {  
            $(this).fadeOut("fast",function(){  
                $(this).attr("src", std);  
                $(this).fadeIn("fast");           
            });  
        })  
    }); 
});
```

Comment: If you could share your HTML markup we could test and help you.

Comment: `<img class="fadeim" src="std.png" alt="Exit"/> ` script simply changes `src="std.png"` into 'src="std-hover.png"'

Comment: [There doesn't seem to be any delay](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/pyCLH/)?

Comment: don't you see white screen between theese images?

Comment: It's because of the fadeout/fadein effect. [Take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/EJPbQ/).

Comment: can we modify it for fade in fade out?

Comment: You already have it with fadeOut/fadeIn.

Comment: How you are doing: You **fade out** first URL - **white backgroud shows** - **you change URL** - **fade in** second url. You **need** two image object for desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you hover the 'first' image, the second one is NOT yet loaded.

Try this way:

```
$('.fadeim').each(function() {

    var std = $(this).attr("src");
    var hover = std.replace(".png", "-hover.png");  

    $(this).clone().insertAfter(this).attr('src', hover).removeClass('fadeim').siblings().css({
        zIndex: '1',
        position:'absolute'
    });
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(600, 0);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(600, 1);
    });

});
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/xb4GL/)

Comment: delay between images still exists

Comment: where's the second demo? i see only one. but delay still exists

Comment: the white screen between two images still exists

Comment: ok. but i don't wanna use css method (write bunch of code for only 1 images transition)  is there any way to fix my solution?

Comment: In what browser? I've tested it even on IE 6,7,8   (if the fiddle link that has issues or on your page?)

Comment: why the second image moves to the left? and try to minimize browser for 1 minutes then take a look at it again. It's fades in and out without mouse hover

Comment: (I'm not having this strang issue...) even with the `.stop()` ?   http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/QvGyB/5/   (THE DEMO works in Opera, Safari, IE6,7,8, Moz)

Comment: Edited my first answer with a working demo - applicable to many buttons

Comment: This is what Marc and I have been talking all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following [what i normally do]:

You can check out my testing link : http://jsfiddle.net/fJFmx/1/

I set a container [fixed width&height] for images. Set the style of for the images to position:absolute and with fixed dimensions.

**HTML example:**

```
<div id='slideContainer'>
    <img src='http://www.ct4me.net/images/dmbtest.gif' />
    <img src='http://pievscake.com/images/test.jpg' />
</div>
```

**Then the Jquery:**

```
$(function() {

    $('#slideContainer img:first').fadeIn();

    $('#slideContainer').hover(function() {
        $('#slideContainer img:first').fadeOut();
        $('#slideContainer img:last').fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $('#slideContainer img:first').fadeIn();
        $('#slideContainer img:last').fadeOut();
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#slideContainer {border:1px solid #ffcc00;width:50px; height:50px;}
#slideContainer img {position:absolute; width:50px; height:50px; display:none;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice. Nitpicking the CSS just for fun, and removing all style attributes from HTML, and using this as CSS: #slideContainer {border:1px solid #ffcc00;width:50px; height:50px;}
#slideContainer img { position:absolute; width:50px; height:50px; display:none; }   tidies up your html a bit as well. :)

Comment: I agree, it is best practice and standard :) .. I used inline styles just for example purpose, in this case.

Comment: ok and what's wrong with my solution? is there any way to fix it? I used preload too but there is still white screen between 2 images

Comment: The problem is that, By switching the source, there will always be a gap in switching, the two images are not on top of each other [think layers]. Let me know if you understand.

Comment: is there something more simplier than you solution? this is bunch of code for only 1 images transition.

Comment: I proposed you this exact solution first, and you said it is not a solution. I also said you can add second image **dynamically** whith jQuery append() function, if you don't want messy HTML code. But hey, accept it, solutions aren't always beautiful.

Comment: "I also said you can add second image dynamically whith jQuery append() function, if you don't want messy HTML code." how??

Comment: I have changed my "messy html" so that the CSS is separate. The html is very simple, the jquery is very basic and you have 2lines of CSS. enjoy

Comment: @RokKralj How come you are not removing the `cloned` object? BTW it's working for me but wanted to get more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place two  elements over one another (via CSS absolute/relative positioning), then you will be able to decrease the opacity of the top one to make it look like it is fading into the bottom one.

After the fadeout is complete, quickly switch the SRC atributes of the images (user won't notice) and prepare for another cycle.

I suggest this HTML (because you only set width&height in one place and children will adapt to the parent size):

```
<div id='slideContainer' style='width:50px; height:50px; position: relative;'>
     <img src='hover.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left: 0px; display:none;' />
     <img src='original.jpg' style='position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left: 0px; display:none;' />
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, it's not the solution.

Comment: Why not? Good luck achieving this effect without this trick, this is the only way.
You still use jQuery and if you want, you can add the second image via jQuery function.

Comment: L0rd DEVdem0rt, solution like yours won't work. What you name the "delay", is the white frame that images animate over. I gueess you want to animate one image onto another, but that is not achievable with only one object - not matter if you preload the second one. How you are doing: You fade out first URL - **white backgroud shows** - you change URL - fade in second url.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use CSS3 for what you're trying to do instead, as the image will not change if someone has JavaScript turned off. Try this CSS:

```
.fadeim {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(std.png) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: background 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background 500ms linear;
    transition: background 500ms linear;
}

.fadeim:hover {
    background: url(std-hover.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

The above code assumes your image is 200×100px; you should change the width and height settings to the same size as the image. So if you open a page with this CSS applied, you'll see the image, and when you hover, the image should fade into the other one. This currently only works in WebKit (Chrome and Safari) and Mozilla (Firefox), so if someone uses an unsupported browser, the page will act exactly the same, but the image will immediately change without fading.

Ad@m

Comment: but it hasn't cross browser support

Answer (score 1):

**The way to solve your problem:**

pre load the second picture like Rok Kralj said,don't load it the second you need it.

otherwise you would have to wait for the browser fetching it from server

**A better way**

set one picture as src,other one as parentNode's background-image. only animate the image.

Because users don't need the blank gap,they just need the transforming for better experience